# How to find the largest semi-circle that fits inside a polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygons

I have seen (and implemented) algorithms that find the 'Pole of Inaccessibility' for a polygon - that allows you to draw the largest circle within it. However, if I wanted to find the largest semi-circle that fits inside a polygon, is there a similar method?

EDIT:
I use this algorithm [MapBox polylabel](https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel) to calculate the largest circle that will fit inside a polygon. Whilst I understand what it does, I can't really see a way to apply it to semi-circles.

I feel as if the answer might start with trying to find the longest line inside the polygon that has the smallest average distance to the boundary, which might align it close to the longest straight(ish) part of said boundary.

I re-implemented this [Largest Rect in a Poly](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/blob/master/src/geom/largestRect.coffee) which I feel could have some bearing on my thoughts above in the way that it searches for longest lines inside the poly.

But its easy to come up with shapes where the largest semi-circle is not really approximated by either the largest circle or the largest rectangle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.) This is a difficult problem, so it is particularly important to do so.

Comment: The positioning of a largest semi-circle within a polygon (perhaps a convex one??) will naturally be more difficult because an additional parameter is involved.  Have you done any research to answer your Question?  Sharing the fruits of that search would expedite the responses of willing Readers.

Comment: I'm not really following the concept here? I'm not a mathematician. If I knew how to do this, I wouldn't be asking, would I? The whole point of me posting was to avoid countless fruitless hours of Googling and trying to understand maths, if someone already knows how to approach the problem. Nevertheless, I'll update the question with my research, such as it is.

Comment: In trade for saving you the countless hours of googling, we ask that you save us hours of trying to answer questions that turn out not to be what folks really need to solve (example: "I need to do arithmetic with 5000-digit numbers", failing to mention that the end result will be the reduction, mod 13, of whatever gets computed...) or the answer to which is beyond their understanding ("I'm 11 years old, and I want to understand Wiles' proof of Fermat. Can you explain it to me without algebra?") So forgive us if we ask a few questions before spending lots of *our* time on your problem.

Comment: This is an extremely hard problem and not being a mathematician does not justify dumping the work on others. If you have absolutely no approach to this problem, then chances are you would not understand the answer either (if there is one).

Comment: I wasn't attempting to 'dump work' on anyone, I was hoping someone with more knowledge than me might be able to say "Aha! you need the Doofenshmirtz variation of the Hurgleflurgle Algorithm" that's all. It usually helps to be very specific when Googling niche-domain knowledge. For instance, I spent a lot of time trying to find polyline simplification routines before finding out I should have been looking for Douglas-Peucker algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

**My Approach Thus Far**

Using the largest rect routine above, I find the largest 2:1 rectangle that will fit.
And (if necessary) move it parallel to the short edge until it is on the boundary.

[image: One]

I then draw a semicircle on each of the long edges, and see if I can make it bigger.

[image: Two] [image: Three]

I then move the rectangle parallel to the short edge again, until it is on the other side.
Then repeat the semicircle jigging around.

[image]

It's not perfect, but it's a decent start.

**EDIT:**
It seems it would also be worth testing the 'internal' semi-circle formed by each line segment of the polyline. There also feels like there is a geometric solution to finding the largest edge-aligned internal semi-circle for each segment, but I can't quite get my head around it yet.